# react-router: Best way to pass props to nested route components in react-router ^2.0.0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing, parent-child

### **Precursor:**

I am refactoring two components, *Photos.js* and *PhotoDetailsModal.js*. Originally they had a relationship like this:

```
<Photos>
   <PhotoDetailsModal/>
</Photos>
```

my route '/photos' looked like the following, and *Photos.js* simply controlled the the rendering of *PhotoDetailsModal* internally through state and a little bit of data-gathering:

```
<Route path="photos" component={Photos}/>
```

If I want to decouple these two components and make a route like this:

```
<Route path="photos" component={Photos}>
  <Route path=":photoId" component={PhotoDetailsModal}>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

How do I pass props into the *PhotoDetailsModal* component? Prior to this re-design, Photos.js simply handled all the data gathering and just passed expanded photo data to `<PhotoDetailsModal/>` internally through some props.

I do know that inside Photos.js I will eventually use `{this.props.children}` to render *PhotoDetailsModal*, **I just want to know how to do all of my data-passing from `<Photos/>` to `<PhotoDetailsModal/>` using this new routing**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With v2/3 of React Router, you will have to use `cloneElement` to re-render the `this.props.children` element with the desired props. Basically, your code will look like this:

```
render() {
  const { children } = this.props
  return (
    <div>
      { children && React.cloneElement(children, { other: 'foo' }) }
    </div>
  )
}
```

The documentation for React Router includes this [passing props to children](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/passing-props-to-children/app.js) example app which does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will try this out. My first impression is that this seems so different from passing props to children internally. Do you think that the current way to do this is somewhat hacky / verbose, and do you think it will get simplified in the future?

Comment: Yes, in v4 you can pass props directly. Routing is reworked so that your routes (the `<Match>` component) actually render their component. (In v2/3 the `<Route>` components are just used for configuration). It is still in alpha and has some bugs, but it should hopefully be released soon.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. One more thing I want to clear-up in my own head: So even though <Route/>'s are just used for configuration, by defining nested routes aren't I actually also defining tangible component relationships?

Comment: You are defining what will be provided to the parent route's component through the `children` prop. What ends up happening is that the most nested component is rendered, then it is passed to its parent route, which renders and passes its element to its parent, all the way up the tree to your root component. You can check the source code starting here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/modules/RouterContext.js#L52 if you want to get a better understanding. Basically, the v2/3 render process is convoluted whereas v4 just uses React, so it is much simpler.